# SPO Groups in SPO Groups

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, groups

Is it possible in Sharepoint Online to add Sharepoint Groups as members of Sharepoint Groups?

I was able to do this in my SP 2010 on-premise.  I could add both Sharepoint groups and AD groups with no problems.

But in my SPO I get a message saying I can't do it!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add one SP group into another SharePoint group. You can only add AD security group inside SP group.  This is by design.  However, you can set one group as owner of another group so that they can manage the access request and other group settings.

Comment: Is there no way to enable it via powershell?

Comment: No we cant do this. Also in SP 2010, i am sure that you are only able to AD group inside SP group, not SP group inside SP group. This is by design.

Comment: Well, I *can* add SP groups to SP groups in my on-premise 2010 Sharepoint Server (Enterprise).  .....  er, okay, I *can* add them and even check their names, but then it gives an error just like the one above.  Okay, I was wrong about that.